# Split a big html file into smaller ones

Tags: html, wordpress, file, import

I have an HTML file with several hundreds `<li>` tags. What I want is that the content of each of those tags be copied to a new file. The file name is not important. The purpose is to add this as posts using [HTML Import for wordpress](http://stephanieleary.com/code/wordpress/html-import). So how could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by first replacing every crlf to space, then replacing every `<li>` tag into a crlf, and then using this vbscript to split every line into a new file:

```
Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile = "index.html"
Set input = FileSystem.OpenTextFile(strFile)
cnt = 0
Do Until input.AtEndOfStream
  strLine = input.ReadLine
  Set output = FileSystem.CreateTextFile("part" & Right("000" & cnt, 3) & ".html", 2, False)
  output.WriteLine(strLine)
  output.Close
  cnt = cnt + 1
Loop
input.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you code in php, in a text editor with a combination of replaces you can convert those li's in a php array, then loop and create the new files.

Comment: Thanks. Used this idea as a base to my solution

Answer (score 0):

Copy the part with all the `<li>` tags and paste it into a file called `list.html`.

Then use jQuery to include `list.html` into your main html file. You could paste this into your main html file:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("list.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to get the data from between the tags you could use this regex `(?<=<li\>)(.*?)(?=<\/li>)` that should match just the `<li>` tags and nothing outside of them.

Comment: Thanks but I really want to output the result to different text files